# Compiling GIMP from source code

Tags: c, compilation, mingw, gimp, msys2

I am trying to edit the GIMP source code directly in order to test algorithms. The problem that I am having is in setting up the compilation of the source code. On the GIMP website, it says to run the below in msys2.exe:

```
pacman -S base-devel \
mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain \
git \
mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk2 \
mingw-w64-x86_64-json-glib \
mingw-w64-x86_64-json-c \
mingw-w64-x86_64-gexiv2 \
mingw-w64-x86_64-lcms2
```

the problem with this is that all the commands below pacman -S base-devel refuse to run. I have successfully completed all previous commands shown [here](https://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Building/Windows). The only error I received was when running pacman -Su due to the packages being previously installed. How may I successfully install the above package list? In addition, if anyone else has done this before is there any advice you can give me?

Below is the result of running the above code
[image]

Comment: As I read it, the lines after the `pacman` one are not commands to run but arguments to pacman (the `\\` is a continuation character), and so would be packages to install.

Comment: Good luck trying to build GIMP on Windows - it is not a development friendly environment. Maybe, instead of trying mingw you could use the new "ubuntu over windows"  feature offered by Microsoft?

Comment: @xenoid Updated the question with my specific problem shown.

Comment: @jsbueno There is a wonderful explanation by Tom Scott on why he prefers windows as a development environment over other operating systems. In addition, I am kind of lazy. Still, might give it a try if windows proves too much of a burden.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you want to test algorithms you can write plugins instead of modifying Gimp. This is a much simpler task whatever the environment. You can even write the plugins in Python... (although C remains an option).

Comment: I didn't (even) tell you to leave Windows -  I've told you to try the Ubuntu environment over Windows Microsoft had made available: http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/